# Is it too early for .net 4 beta 2 migration

Tags: .net

Just wondering if it is too early to migrate to .net fw beta 2.
We have a wpf app which uses graphics such as images, shapes and also flash in it intensively.
Just wondering how others experiences have been.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the audience for your app - and your timescale.

I don't think you should be *releasing* your software under 4.0b2 but going through the act of porting and validating it in preparation for the release seems more reasonable. For example, if you're going to add some .NET 4-specific features, then developing those now is fine.

I believe the release candidate is meant to be shipping soonish, so you *may* want to hold off for that to avoid another uninstall/install cycle, but .NET 4b2 and VS2010b2 are pretty stable IME. The framework seems more stable than VS to me at the moment, but that's always been the case.

A bigger question is whether you want your app to require .NET 4 to start with... who's likely to want to run your app? Consumers won't have it (but they will have 3.5 if they're running Windows 7) but may be willing to install it; many corporates may have to go through a long vetting procedure before allowing it to be installed. I don't particularly want to put you off, but you need to think about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Pretty much. If you want your code compatible with the world. At least wait until beta ends.

Comment: Hi Mark
In general i understand why you say that. But i am wondering if you have more specific info.
Thanks
N

Comment: More specific as in "don't do it, ya clown"? :-) By all means run a test project which periodically moves your source across to .net4, but, in the name of whatever deities you believe in, keep your real code in a stable development environment.

Comment: Great, Thanks to Jon, Alex, Allen and other for your input.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having spent the last year or so researching VS2010 for my book I would say yes it is too early to migrate projects to VS2010 - particularly for WPF applications.

For simple console or ASP.net apps VS2010 b2 appears to be pretty stable but for WPF projects the designer is very unstable and frequently locked my machine up. Developing with this would be a frustrating experience!

There is supposed to be an RC next month so I would wait until then at the earliest. There are some great new designer features for WPF development (full support for Silverlight design time, ability to see control errors, binding dialogues, resource selection off the top of my head) through that will make it well worth the wait.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF editor in VS 2010 is much, much nicer than the previous one. However, the IDE also tends to crash or freeze up from time to time, so I wouldn't trust it for production code.

Right now I'm using it to build prototypes. Though I know we won't deploy it until RTM (currently expected in April), at least I can start showing people what I can do.